# submitting the same form twice and form.$valid

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that is used to scan barcodes. When one is input, an `ng-click` function triggers and reads in the form and the barcode. Like so:

```
<form name="vm.form">
    <input ng-model="vm.scannedBarcode"
       required
       oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a barcode number')"
       onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"
       type="text">
   <input type="submit" 
       ng-click="vm.addBarcode(vm.form, vm.scannedBarcode)" 
       value="Add">      
</form>
```

And then, the controller:

```
vm.addBarcode = function(form, barcode) {
    if(form.$valid){
        console.log("okay");
        ...
        // add the barcode to an array of barcodes
    }
}
```

Notice that the location *doesn't change* after form submission. The new barcode is just pushed onto an array of existing barcodes and then displayed in a table below the form. This is key, I think.

The above works, but only for the *first* barcode scanned, say `1111`. Then I scan a second barcode, say `2222`. Now `form` is set to both `pristine` and `invalid` even though the `barcode` is set to `2222`, as it should be.

In brief, how can I submit the same form twice?

Thanks!

Comment: Get rid of using native dom validity methods and only use angular ones. Never ever any reason to use `onchange` , `oninvalid` , `onclick` etc in angular. In fact should use `novalidate` on form and let angular manage it all

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. However there is possibility that second call of the addBarcode happened before the first ones process is fully complete or before digest cycle is complete. Myabe you need try $timeout like this.
        vm.addBarcode= $timeout(function(form, barcode) {
    if(form.$valid){
        console.log("okay");
        ...
        // add the barcode to an array of barcodes
    }
});